# Speed up simple update statement in postgres for 1 million rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, sql-update

I have a very simple sql update statement in postgres.

```
UPDATE p2sa.observation SET file_path = replace(file_path, 'path/sps', 'newpath/p2s')
```

The observation table has 1513128 rows. The query so far has been running for around 18 hours with no end in sight.

The file_path column is not indexed so I guess it is doing a top to bottom scan but it seems a bit excessive the time. Probably replace is also a slow operation.

Is there some alternative or better approach for doing this one off kind of update which affects all rows. It is essentially updating an old file path to a new location. It only needs to be updated once or maybe again in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: That really seems a long time. Did you check if it's maybe [waiting for a lock](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring)?

Comment: Is 'path/sps' realy in every row? If not you could add a where file_path like '%path/sps%'.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you could do a while loop to update in batches.

Try this to see how it performs.

```
Declare @counter int 
Declare @RowsEffected int 
Declare @RowsCnt int 
Declare @CodeId int 
Declare @Err int
DECLARE @MaxNumber int = (select COUNT(*) from p2sa.observation)
SELECT @COUNTER = 1
SELECT @RowsEffected = 0


WHILE ( @RowsEffected < @MaxNumber)
BEGIN 
SET ROWCOUNT 10000


UPDATE p2sa.observation 
SET file_path = replace(file_path, 'path/sps', 'newpath/p2s')
where file_path != 'newpath/p2s'

SELECT @RowsCnt = @@ROWCOUNT ,@Err = @@error 
IF @Err <> 0 
BEGIN 
Print 'Problem Updating the records' 
BREAK
END 
ELSE 

SELECT @RowsEffected = @RowsEffected + @RowsCnt 
PRINT 'The total number of rows effected :'+convert(varchar,@RowsEffected) 

            /*delaying the Loop for 10 secs , so that Update is completed*/    

     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'         
 END
 SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: as you can see it waits 10 secs, so its sure that the rows have been updated, You can tweak this time or your rowcount based on what you see. If you have 10.000 rows and a wait of 10 sec your execute time will be around 25 minutes.